# how to test whether a Link from Router worked? Jest/RTL

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

with RTL how do i check the to='/login' in Link to be true since RTL library mainly grabs by testid or text.

current page testing

```
import React from 'react';
import Proptypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Navigation(props) {
  return (
    <nav className="header__nav">
      <Link to="/login">
        <button type="button" className="header__login">LOGIN</button>
      </Link>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

test

```
describe('Navigation Content', () => {
    test('clicking login button', () => {
      const props = jest.fn();
      const { getByTestId, getByText } = render (
        <Navigation popUpHandler={props}/>, { wrapper: MemoryRouter }
      );

        expect((<Link>).toHaveAttribute('to', '/login')
    }) 
})
```

page i am trying to render to when clicked

```
function LoginForm() {

  return (
    <div className="login">
        <h1 className="entryheader__header">Login</h1>
    </div>
  )
export default LoginForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try rendering your component like this:

```js
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
...
...

 const { getByTestId, getByText } = render(<YourComponent {...props}/>, { wrapper: MemoryRouter });

fireEvent.click(getByText('LOGIN'));

expect(getByText('some-text-on-login-page')).toBeInTheDocument();
```

This will wrap your component with the memory router rather than you doing it manually.

You can also try using `BrowserRouter` instead of `MemoryRouter` in your test file..

Comment: oh i had no idea you could wrap a component like that, thanks! but as for the expect, it still doesnt redirect me to the other page. It shows a snapshot of the current page im still rendering

Comment: Can you please share both the login page component + your test file

Comment: any specific reason you are using `props=jest.fn()`, there doesn't seem to be any props used in the Navigation component..

Comment: i have a popuphandler function many codes down in the navigation component, i didnt think i needed to paste that into here cuz its a lot of code past that

Comment: Could you try using `BrowserRouter` instead of MemoryRouter in your test file? BrowserRouter is also a named import available from `react-router-dom` package

Comment: okay, i just updated with browser router, im still not redirecting to the other page

Comment: Is it possible you can show me your full code, perhaps github repo link? it will be faster if i can download it and play with it..

Comment: I decided to change it up a bit to not test a button that renders to a another page, i noticed a lot of dicussions about i shouldnt be testing whether a button renders. So i decided to test whether my Link has the correct to=/login value. Which i was also working on. But with RTL im unsure how to grab a tag, only know Enzyme can do that. Updated code

Comment: here is an article on how to do it - `https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/`, so i don't think its a bad practice to test whether your screen changes because its helpful in avoiding accidental typos in screen names or if you want to test what happens when the route you are trying to go to doesn't exist.

Comment: ahh you do have a point there,I guess given RTL tests more on UI behaviour, makes more sense to test for page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had an answer to this question but I do feel like I can say the following:
I wouldn't do

```
<Link to="/login">
  <button type="button" className="header__login">LOGIN</button>
</Link>
```

because this will render non-valid HTML markup. It breaks accessibility rules to start